# Как удалять последовательные дубликаты по определённому столбцу?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Представим, что есть некая программа, которая отдает данные вот в таком формате:

```
$ cat foo.bs
#!/bin/bash

echo "[INFO] Инициализация временных сдвигов"
sleep 1
echo "[INFO] Подготовка к временному увеличению скорости света"
sleep 1
echo "[WARN] u.speed_of_light: NaN"
sleep 1
echo "[INFO] Скорость света увеличена, начинаем создание темной материи"
sleep 1
echo "[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException: null"

$ ./foo.bs
[INFO] Инициализация временных сдвигов
[INFO] Подготовка к временному увеличению скорости света
[WARN] u.speed_of_light: NaN
[INFO] Скорость света увеличена, начинаем создание темной материи
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Что хотелось бы получить:

```
[INFO] Подготовка к временному увеличению скорости света
[WARN] u.speed_of_light: NaN
[INFO] Скорость света увеличена, начинаем создание темной материи
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Пошаговое воспроизведение:

1. Выводим `[INFO] Инициализация временных сдвигов`
2. Перезаписываем предыдущую строку, потому что у нее флаг `[INFO]`, теперь последняя отображаемая строка `[INFO] Инициализация временных сдвигов`
3. Выводим новую строку `[WARN] u.speed_of_light: NaN.`
4. Выводим новую строку `[INFO] Скорость света увеличена, начинаем создание темной материи` потому что перезаписывать варнинги нельзя
5. Выводим новую строку `[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException: null.`

Необходимо именно перезаписывать предыдущую выведенную строку (см. пункт 2), поскольку необходима индикация процесса.

Подскажите, есть ли стандартные методы для осуществления этого? Набросал простой скрипт, который решает конкретную задачу (хотя есть пара тонких моментов), но хотелось бы иметь стандартные средства для подобного.

```
#!/bin/bash

last_line=""

while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ $line != \[INFO\]* ]];
    then
        echo -e "\n$line"
    elif [[ $last_line == \[INFO\]* ]];
    then
        echo -en "\r$line"
    else
        echo -en "$line"
    fi

    last_line="$line"
done
```

Comment: Т.е. задача -- выводить на экран только последнее из последовательности INFO сообщений? А чем скрипт не устраивает? Можно добавить вывод пустой строки в самом его конце. Можно не хранить всю предыдущую строку, а хранить только ее тип (мелкая оптимизация). Или Вы хотите, чтобы при перенаправлении в файл "лишние" INFO там тоже не появлялись?

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы метки `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR` каким-либо образом настраивались. Скрипт, в принципе, устраивает, но не хочется каждый раз его руками куда-нибудь таскать. Может есть возможность воспользоваться стандартными средствами

Comment: Нам с коллегами (сидящими сейчас в комнате) неизвестно. Часто проще написать самому, чем искать.

Comment: хороший вопрос, но смысл абсолютно непонятен из перечисленных пунктов (1-5), и ясность проливает только результат работы прилагающегося скрипта, который (результат), к сожалению, не приведён в вопросе.

Comment: На самом деле, конечный результат тоже не внес бы ясности, поскольку я дал некорректный пример входных данных в самом начале (cat выводил весь файл сразу, без задержек между линиями). Исправлено, надеюсь, цель стала более понятна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вот такая минипрограмма для интерпретатора `awk`

```
x!=$номер;{x=$номер}
```

(где `номер` — это номер сортируемого столбца) делает примерно то, что вам нужно: удаляет последовательные дубликаты, встречющиеся в указанном столбце:

```
$ cat foo | awk 'x!=$1;{x=$1}'
[INFO] Инициализация временных сдвигов
[WARN] u.speed_of_light: NaN
[INFO] Скорость света увеличена, начинаем создание темной материи
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

но, как видите, печатается содержимое той строки, которая встретилась первой.

чтобы печаталось содержимое *последней* из встреченных строк, можно, конечно, «помудрить» с программой (насколько я понимаю, существенно её усложнив), а можно просто «перевернуть» содержимое файла — чтобы первой шла последняя строка, второй предпоследняя и т.д., а после обработки — «перевернуть» опять. сделать это можно программой `tac` (даже в названии отражён ей смысл: `cat` «наоборот»):

```
$ tac foo | awk 'x!=$1;{x=$1}' | tac
[INFO] Подготовка к временному увеличению скорости света
[WARN] u.speed_of_light: NaN
[INFO] Скорость света увеличена, начинаем создание темной материи
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

---

идея минипрограммы позаимствована отсюда: http://www.unixcl.com/2009/05/remove-duplicate-consecutive-fields-or.html

---

#### обновление

придумал, как обойтись без `tac`. минипрограмма, правда, значительно усложняется:

```
$ cat foo | awk 'END{print y}{if(x!=$1&&x!=""){print y};x=$1;y=$0}'
```

чтобы сортировать по другому столбцу, надо подставить его номер вместо `1` в оба вхождения `$1`.

#### обновление2

из уточнений стало понятно, что требуется не просто конечный результат, а «интерактивное шоу», когда последняя выведенная строка стирается, если следующая за ней начинается тем же самым словом.

тогда можно сделать примерно так:

```
#!/bin/bash

prevline=""
prevtag=""

while read line; do
  newtag=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
  if [ -n "$prevline" ]; then
    if [ "$newtag" == "$prevtag" ]; then
      echo -n "$prevline" | sed 's/./\x08/g'
    else
      echo
    fi
  fi
  echo -n "$line"
  prevtag=$newtag
  prevline=$line
done
echo
```

`\x08` — это символ [«забоя» (*backspace*)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace). к сожалению, программа `sed`, которой я воспользовался в данном случае, не воспринимает распрастранённую escape-последовательность `\b` в качестве данного символа. связано это с тем, что на данную escape-последовательность «подвешена» функция определения границы слова.

Comment: Похоже, я действительно некорректо объяснил принцип работы. Мне нужно именно перезаписать предыдущую строку, т.е. я хочу видеть индикацию процесса. Сейчас обновлю пост.

Comment: Соответственно, решение с awk выводит правильный конечный результат, но во время выполнения оно будет "подвисать" на всех блоках `[INFO]`, поскольку будет искать в них последнюю строку.

Comment: а, так вам требуется «интерактивное шоу». я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да, спасибо, все работает. Небольшой вопрос - если строка слишком большая и не влазит на одну строку терминала - такое реально отловить?

Comment: `$ echo -n "blabla"`
`-n blabla`
`$ echo -n "blabla" | sed 's/./\x08/g'`
`x08x08x08x08x08x08x08x08x08`

Comment: @soon, ну, в таком случае надо уже целую программу писать. и задействовать в ней что-нибудь типа ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

```
./foo.bs | awk '{$1==l?p="\r":p="\n"}{printf "%s%-80s",p,$0}{l=$1}'
```

По поводу длинных строк. Тут вам, для начала, необходимо определиться с тем, что вы хотите получить.

Можно, например, отключить перенос строк: `printf %b '\033[?7l'`. Тогда длинные строки будут "обрезаться" по краю окна.

Если нужно выводить строку целиком, с переносом, то можно заморочиться с backspace (работает далеко не везде), либо со сложным высчитыванием реального количества выведенных строк (`tput cols` в помощь). В общем, простого пути нет.

Ну и следует помнить, что все эти пляски со спецсимволами очень сильно зависят от настроек как терминала на стороне клиента, так и на стороне сервера.

Comment: Отлично работает, спасибо, но что если строки длинее 80 символов?

Comment: @soon ну так поставьте число побольше :) Вам в любом случае придется затирать остаток предыдущей строки, каким бы решением не воспользовались

Comment: В том и проблема, что просто поставить число больше 80 не помогает :) Поскольку строка слишком длинная, она переносится. Если мы ставим, скажем, 100 символов вместо 80, то стирается только новая строка, а данные остаются на экране.

Comment: @soon Так. Расскажите тогда подробно, что вы хотите видеть в случае  длинной строки? Должна ли она переноситься или нет? Нужно ли обрезать очень длинные строки? и т.д. А то выходит техзадание из разряда "поди туда, не знаю куда

Comment: Представим, что выводится строка длинной 100 символов и она не помещается в одну строку терминала. После нее выводится строка длинной 10 символов и она помещается на одну строку терминала. Таким образом, она должна затереть все строки в терминале, которые заняла предыдущая строка длинной 100 символов.

Comment: @soon дополнил ответ